# Seemingly random undefined references

Tags: c, malloc

Have a decent malloc package, just trying to finish the realloc when disaster struck.
Half of the time it compiles correctly, the other half of the time, nearly every function in the package is "undefined."

```
mdriver.c:(.text+0x1e3): undefined reference to `mm_init'
mdriver.c:(.text+0x221): undefined reference to `mm_realloc'
mdriver.c:(.text+0x255): undefined reference to `mm_free'
```

...and so on, for nearly every function plus "team," although I don't have any function named that.
I've literally shuffled the number in the assignment of copySize around and occasionally gotten both outcomes, regardless of digit choice and now, any number I use gives me the massive failure. It uses a makefile called mdriver.c to compile.

```
 /*
  * mm_realloc - Implemented simply in terms of mm_malloc and mm_free
  */
 void *mm_realloc(void *bp, size_t size)
 {
     void *obp = bp;
     void *nbp;
     size_t copySize = 10;
     size_t asize = ALIGN(size);

     nbp = mm_malloc(asize);
     if (nbp == NULL)
       return NULL;
     copySize = *(size_t *)((char *)obp - SIZE_T_SIZE + 2);
     if (asize < copySize)
       copySize = asize;
     memcpy(nbp, obp, copySize);
     mm_free(obp);
     return nbp;
 }
```

Comment: How do you build the program? What errors *exactly* are you getting? And can you *please* try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead of that wall of code?

Comment: Okay, there we go. Pretty sure the issue is in realloc, but honestly I have no idea.

Comment: @Bizshnips Just to clarify: did you actually name your makefile as `mdriver.c` as you say in your question?  I would recommend renaming it to `makefile` and having a rule for compiling `mdriver.c` in the makefile.  I'd appreciate it if you could also post your makefile.

Comment: Note: `mm_free(void *bp)` needs to cope properly with `mm_free(NULL)`.  Since it appears the problem appears to be linker related, suspect the issue is in the makefile and not code.

Comment: Sorry, the makefile is makefile, mdriver.c is a testing program.

Comment: If you're using a testing module, you need to make sure you are including all the same librarys as the main code... The error is being generated by the LINK program, telling you it cannot find the functions you list. If no other programmer is saying the missing functions are theirs, then you are most likely missing a library (.LIB) that is not being included in your cutdown\test build.